# Escaped line break tag in tooltip on election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tooltips, beta-sites

Over on Lifehacks (a beta site with the standard beta template) we're having an election. I just cast my votes and was presented this tooltip:

[image]

Please fix the escaped line break tag so it either displays an actual new line or is simply replaced with a space.

Comment: Fix incoming!<br/>In 6-8 months.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fixed.

> [image: Shadow comment]

And though I am posting this almost exactly 6 months after the above comment, the actual fix went up yesterday.

Comment: You deserve six hearts: ♥♥♥♥♥♥